# What's the best way to make my practice room sound better?

Tags: home-studio, studio-design, space, sound-dampening, reflection

I have a practice space in my garage (20' x 20'). It has a Cement floor that I have covered with a few area rugs. I have a drum set, bass, guitar, pa...

Initially the drums sounded awful. Lots of reflections going on. They are in one of the corners of the garage. At some point I hung a blanket on each wall behind the set. This helped improve the overall sound quite a bit.

I just acquired an old King Size memory foam mattress pad which I don't need. I have been thinking of somehow hanging it where one of the blankets are. I was watching a video last night and saw a practice room with sound dampening foam wedges placed throughout the room. It made me question the best use of this memory foam.

I understand that memory foam and actual sound foam are way different but I figure if the blankets helped than the foam should be even better.

I am wondering if it would be worth it / better to cut the foam into sections and hang them throughout the room?

What about building small wooden frames that angles the foam away from the wall?
(I think thats how the sound wedges were designed in the video)

If I do split the foam is there a strategic size / placement that would be best?
1' x 1' sections, 3' x 3' /  5" apart, 2' apart, higher up, lower to the ground, etc..?

I am not worried about noise level leaving the space I just want it to try to achieve the best sound inside the space with what I've got.

Comment: Have you done anything with the ceiling?  You may want to go to an audio forum such as audiokarma or stereophile.  There you can have discussion and there is already much info on sound treatment options. Also there is much info to be learned on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=acoustic+sound+panels  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLk6fQVcoSw

Comment: Sometimes you just get lucky. In the 80s my home studio had a bad boom at about 120Hz. I found that opening my wardrobe door 8" completely killed it. [It was in the corner, it made a bass trap… something I'd no clue about at the time]